# JHipster 7.1.0 ReactJS Form Cross-field Validation

Tags: reactjs, jhipster

How can I handle form Cross-field Validation in a Jhipster form ? (build with ReactJS)
For example I have this

> ```
>    <ValidatedForm defaultValues={defaultValues()} onSubmit={saveEntity}>
> ```

> ```
>           <ValidatedField
>             label="Person Number"
>             id="reservation-personNumber"
>             name="personNumber"
>             data-cy="personNumber"
>             type="number"
>             validate={{
>               required: { value: true, message: 'This field is required.' },
>               min: { value: 1 },
>               max: { value: 1000, message: 'This field cannot be more than 1000.'},
>               validate: v => isNumber(v) || 'This field should be a number.',
>             }}/>
> ```

> ```
>           <ValidatedField
>             label="Special Diet Number"
>             id="reservation-specialDietNumber"
>             name="specialDietNumber"
>             data-cy="specialDietNumber"
>             type="number"
>             validate={{
>               required: { value: true, message: 'This field is required.' },
>               min: { value: 1, message: 'This field should be at least 1.' },
>               max: {
>                 value: 1000,
>                 message: `This field cannot be more than 1000}.`,
>               },
>               validate: v => isNumber(v) || 'This field should be a number.',
>             }}/> 
>           
>     </ValidatedForm>
> ```

I would like to set the maximum of the "Special Diet Number" field equal to the "Person Number" field entered by the user.

Thanks a lot,